# C++ - AF_UNIX socket hangs

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm currently trying to get a client/daemon communication via an `AF_UNIX` socket up and running.

At the moment the client successfully sends a message, the daemon receives and processes it and then should send the message back.
Well, that's where the problem is. As soon as the daemon tries to send the message back nothing happens, the client hangs, trying to read a message, and if I kill the client the daemon dies with it.

Following is the daemon code:

```
//successful call to accept, I have a file descriptor now...
int c = 0;
while((c = recv(fd, (char*)&buf[0], bufferSize, 0)))
{
    if(c == -1 || c == 0)
        break;
    tmp.append(buf.begin(), buf.begin()+c);
}

writeLog(tmp);
tmp = evaluateMsg(tmp);
writeLog(tmp);

//I assume this send call is hanging
if(send(fd, tmp.c_str(), tmp.size(), 0) < 0)
    writeLog("Could not write message back!");

close(fd);
```

And this is the client code:

```
//connect(); is successful
//send(); as well - the recv(); call is hanging forever
while((c = recv(sockfd, (char*)&buf[0], 1024, 0)))
{
    if(c == -1)
    {
       cout<<"Error";
       break;
    }   
    else if(c == 0)
        break;
    tmp.append(buf.begin(), buf.begin()+c);
}
```

Please note that the code is heavily cut down for the sake of simplicity and readability (especially the code to `daemonize` and create the actual `AF_UNIX` socket (which are both successful)).

**UPDATE:**

I could verify that the client-side `recv()` call is never returning, which means that the daemon-side `send()` call is hanging. Why?

Comment: After the client sends the message to your code, seems it close the socket .That would make the `send()` fail

Comment: No it doesn't. Unfortunately it's not that simple (;

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: _"I assume this send call is hanging"_ ... don't assume, check. Just attach the debugger of your choice and see what's happening.

Comment: You're right. I could verify that the `send()` call on the daemon-side is hanging and the client-side `recv()` call never returns.

Comment: This code is not enough (we don't know, how do you setup your socekts, what happens on evaluateMsg etc.. Please give us a minimal working example.

Comment: Is the daemon being terminated due to a SIGPIPE signal?  if so, then putting a call to signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) at the top of the daemon's main() should avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason that the daemon side `recv()` loop will end. Why would `recv()` return 0 or -1 if the socket is still open?

You should understand when the client finished sending data on the application level, the content should make it clear, and then finish the `recv()` loop and continue to the `send()` part of the server.

Comment: `recv()` should return 0 if it can't read anymore bytes, shouldn't it?

Comment: And it actually does, I could verify this via the `writeLog()` calls which show me the received message and the processed answer.

Comment: @MäxMüller AFAIK recv() return 0 when the socket was closed by the other side (orderly shutdown).

Comment: That's odd, because as I said the daemon actually exits the `recv()` loop and processes the message, while the client does not (either because the server hangs on sending, or the client hangs on receiving)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @EugenePodskal It can explain the reason why the recv() on the client's side is hanging forever which was the question.

Comment: @selalerer Yes, you are probably right. But at the same time it doesn't propose the solution to the actual problem. So it is more of a half-answer. At least from the first look - I basically know nothing of Unix socket programming.

Comment: @EugenePodskal You're right. I now added a proposition of a way to solve the problem too.

Answer (score -1):

Alright, the solution was pretty simple.
@selalerer was right about the return value of `recv()` which leads to this working code snippet:

```
while((c = recv(fd, (char*)&buf[0], bufferSize, 0)))
{
    if(c == -1)
        /* handle error */
    tmp.append(buf.begin(), buf.begin()+c);

    if(c < bufferSize)
        //no more to read, therefore stop reading
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution. If the other side sends exactly `bufferSize` bytes and you read them in one go, you'll still call `recv` again and wait for data that's never going to come. (The correct way to do it was explained in selalerer's answer.)

Comment: Well you're right in general, though for my case it is not possible, because the data can not get exactly `bufferSize` bytes long. But I understand your critique and know that the client should end the content with a specific message.

Comment: I suspect you are reasoning incorrectly. There are only two possibilities. One is that the message is always smaller than `bufferSize`. In that case, your test will *always* `break`. So why test? The other possibility is if the message can be larger than `bufferSize`, but then how can you ensure that the last piece you read isn't exactly `bufferSize` bytes, in which case you will loop and wait for data that will never arrive.